# Is there a way to circle charges in chemfig?

Tags: chemfig, circles

Id like to have a little circle around my minuses in my chemfig:

```
\chemname{\schemestart
\chemfig[][scale=.7]{*6(-=-=(-OH)-=)}
\arrow{->[H$^+$]}
\chemleft[\subscheme{
\chemfig[][scale=.6]{*6(-=-=(-O\textsuperscript{-})-=)}
\arrow{<->}[0,0.97]
\chemfig[][scale=.6]{*6(-=-{-}-(=O)-=)}
\arrow{<->}[0,0.97]
\chemfig[][scale=.6]{*6(-{-}-=-(=O)-=)}
\arrow{<->}[0,0.97]
\chemfig[][scale=.6]{*6(=-=-(=O)-{-}-)}
}\chemright]
\schemestop}{Induktiver Effekt beim Phenol}
```

I need some code for a minus in a circle instead of just a minus... Hopefully you can help!

[image: Result]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use math symbols inside chemfig, so `\ominus` and `\oplus`are useful for this:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\renewcommand*\printatom[1]{\ensuremath{\mathsf{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\sffamily \chemfig[scale=.6]{*6(-{\ominus}-=-(-O|^{\ominus})-=)}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

With `\textcircled{-}` I basically found what I was looking for... But maybe there is a build-in function in chemfig?

Comment: And what's the command for them?

Answer (score 1):

The `chemmacros` package offers symbols for formal charges, `\fplus` and `\fminus`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}

\begin{document}

$+$ $\oplus$ \fplus \par
$-$ $\ominus$ \fminus \par

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This yields a more aesthetically appealing result than that from use of either \textcircled or \oplus.