# chemfig: lewis structure

Tags: vertical-alignment, chemfig

Currently working on corrosion of CaCO3:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\[
[Ca^{2+};
\chemfig{O - C (=[6]O) (-[8]O) }] + 2 \chemfig{H-Cl|}   \hspace{4em}|\Delta H<0
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: CaCO3 typesetting]

But I need some help to fix some issues:

- Where did the Cl in HCl go?
- How do I draw the electron pairs around the O-atoms (see picture below)?
- Can I vertically center the lewis structure of CO3 inside the formula somehow?

[image: How I want CO3 to look like]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable  document that shows the problem.

Comment: You probably want to have a look at the `\Lewis` command in the chemfig documentation and the commands on typesetting chemical equations.

Comment: Should be complete now @BambOo

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but perhaps worth to keep in mind: The carbonate anion does according to the VSEPR theory, exhibit a trigonal planar molecular geometry, while the sketch in your question shows a T-shaped geometry.

Comment: @leandriis I love it when people talk dirty ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\schemestart
\chemleft[
  \subscheme{
    \chemfig{Ca^{2+}} \arrow{0}[,0] \hspace{5mm}
    \chemfig{{\chemabove[-0.5pt]{\lewis{246,O}}{\scriptstyle\hspace{-7mm}\ominus}}- C (=[6]O) -[8]{\chemabove[-0.5pt]{\lewis{026,O}}{\scriptstyle\hspace{7mm}\ominus}}{}}}
  \hspace{5mm}
\chemright]
+2 \chemfig{HCl}
\hspace{4em}
$|\Delta H<0$
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

In the above example, I have made use of the `\lewis` command in order to add the free electron pairs to the oxygen atoms. For the circled charges, I have used `\ominus` as described [in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/354574/134144) and on page 42 (section 12.2 Add a superscript without modifying a bond) of the [chemfig manual](http://mirror.las.iastate.edu/tex-archive/macros/generic/chemfig/chemfig-en.pdf). In order to vertically center the formula, I have used an invisible `\arrow` as described in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/115279/134144). For the square brackets, I have used `\chemleft[` and `\chemright]` as described on page 54 (8 Subscheme) of the [chemfig manual](http://mirror.las.iastate.edu/tex-archive/macros/generic/chemfig/chemfig-en.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions :

- The Cl disappeared because the `|` has seemingly no sense for `chemfig` at least in that position, which probably leads to a non warned error.
- Drawing the electron pairs can be achieved using the `\lewis` command as pointed out by TeXnician. Please see section 8 p 30 of the [`chemfig` manual](https://ctan.crest.fr/tex-archive/macros/generic/chemfig/chemfig-en.pdf)

Please see the modified (although incomplete) example below.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{bmatrix}
Ca^{2+}; & 
\chemfig{
\lewis{2 4 6,\chemabove[0.8pt]{O}{\scriptstyle\hspace{-6mm}\ominus}}-
C (=[6]\lewis{7 5,O})-
\lewis{0 2 6,\chemabove[0.8pt]{O}{\scriptstyle\hspace{6mm}\ominus}}}\quad
\end{bmatrix} + 2 \chemfig{H-\lewis{0,Cl}}   \hspace{4em}|\Delta H<0
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, but I have another question: if I render your solution, I am missing the [ before the Ca2+. How do I fix this?